# Restoring / deleting soft deleted items

Tags: eve

I am using Python Eve with the `soft_delete` enabled for some resources of my REST backend and I meet a problem to **really** delete from the Mongo DB a soft deleted item.

My application workflow involves: 
 - creating an item: *POST /item* with unique name
 - deleting an item: *DELETE /item*
 - creating an item: *POST /item* with the same unique name

On the third step, the item is still existing in the DB but it is `_deleted: True`. How should I restore this item when the user *POST /item* ?

I know that a *PUT /item* or *PATCH /item* will do the trick but my user do not know that he must PUT/PATCH rather than POSTing ...

I tried to use the `deleteitem_internal` function inside an `on_pre_POST_...` hook function but it raises a 404 error.

I suppose that I should `patch_internal` my item with the POSTed data and then abort the request. Is this solution the best one to implement when one wants to restore a soft deleted item ?

Comment: You need to really delete, or you need to restore the document?

Comment: Indeed, I need to restore the document...